# MongoDb fetch subset instead of whole record

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB document structure like this:

```
 [
   {
      "locale":"en",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "locale":"ru",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"ruValue"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and I need to get the translation with name `translation1` for locale `en`. I'm trying to do it like this: `db.translations.find({"locale" : "en", "translation.name": "translation1"} )` but it returning whole locale row, with all translations instead of just `translation1`. I'm new to MongoDB, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, probably I need to use aggregation ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$elemMatch` for this.

```
db.translations.find({"locale" : "en"}, 
                     { translations: { $elemMatch: { name: "translation1" } } } )
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e845ba1005e625a6237d2e0"),
    "translations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "translation1",
            "value" : "enValue"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could also use the [`$` projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). Not sure which is better.

Comment: well, I just tried `db.translations.find({"locale" : "en"}, 
                     { translations: { $elemMatch: { name: "translation1" } } } ` and result is still whole document row : `{"_id":"5e845b2a2953d9001010fbc0","locale":"en","translations":[{"name":"translation1","value":"enValue"},{"name":"translation2","value":"enValue"},{"name":"translation3","value":"enValue"}]}`

Comment: what is MongoDB version? because in my server it is working.

Comment: but depends on documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/ it should work...

Comment: version is 4.2.1

Comment: hmm, I think the issue is on playground I'm using https://www.mplay.run/mongodb-online-terminal. I just  run query in my mongo CLI and all works there. Thank you !